# Équivalent de "to give someone a run for their money" ?

Tags: anglais, locutions

Y a-t-il une locution française qui rend en francais la locution anglaise *[to give someone a run for their money](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-give-someone-a-run-for-their-money)* ?

> If you say that someone could give someone else a run for their money, you mean you think they are almost as good as the other person.
>
> E.g. If he's my chief opposition, I can give him a run for his money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je trouve la définition du Collins difficile à comprendre, ambiguë avec son *they* singulier et cette *other person* dont on ne sait pas trop bien qui elle est.

En voici d'autres, qui me paraissent plus claires :

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/give-someone-a-run-for-his-or-her-money): to be as good at something as someone who is extremely good
- [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=run%20for%20your%20money): Figurative language meaning to challenge someone
  *Your car might be fast but my car would give you a run for your money*
- [The free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+run+for+money): To challenge one's ability, fortitude, or patience.
  *Don't underestimate our opponents today—I think they'll give us a run for our money.

  Having an infant and a toddler sure is giving me a run for my money.*

Une expression idiomatique qui peut convenir est ***donner du fil à retordre à quelqu'un***

> - Si c'est mon principal opposant, je peux lui donner du fil à retordre.
> - Ta voiture est peut-être rapide, mais la mienne va lui donner du fil à retordre.
> - Ne sous-estimes pas tes opposants aujourd'hui, je pense qu'ils te donneront du fil à retordre.
> - Avoir deux enfants en bas age avec si peu d'intervalle, c'est sûr que ça me donne du fil à retordre.

Attention, l'expression *[en avoir pour son argent](http://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/35127)* suggérée ailleurs a bien une proximité apparente, mais la signification n'est pas du tout la même. L'utiliser serait un contresens.

- Dire à quelqu'un qu'il va en avoir pour son argent, ça veut dire qu'il ne sera pas déçu, qu'il va être bénéficiaire de son investissement.
- Dire à quelqu'un qu'on va lui donner un *run for his money*, ça veut dire qu'il va être défié et qu'il risque de perdre sa place, son rang.

Answer (score 0):

Une expression française ressemble étrangement à celle en question ; c'est « **en avoir pour son argent** ».

Traduction

- S'il est mon plus grand adversaire je peux faire en sorte qu' **il en ait**  pour son argent.

Cela signifie « offrir une forte opposition », ce qui correspond à l'anglais. On trouve cette traduction dans le dictionnaire français-anglais « Harrap's » (15e impression, 1989); c'est de registre familier.

Il y a aussi l'expression « en donner pour son argent à qqn », laquelle ressemble aussi étrangement à l'expression anglaise. On peut l'utiliser au sens figuré;

> (Dictionnaire Académie) On leur en a donné pour leur argent, ils ont reçu ce qui correspondait au prix payé, et même davantage et, fig., **ils n'ont eu que ce qu'ils méritaient**.

Elle ne semble pas tout à fait équivalente cependant, bien que DeepL donne la traduction suivante ;

> S'il est mon principal opposant, je peux lui en donner pour son argent.

Traduction

- S'il est mon plus grand adversaire je peux  **lui en donner** pour son argent.

Dire cela ou selon le dictionnaire de l'Académie « faire en sorte qu'*il ait ce qu'il mérite* » peut signifier « faire en sorte qu'il soit vaincu ».

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Jlliagre, "*en donner pour son argent*" n'a pas du tout le même sens, c'est un faux ami.